# Vue js php error messages not showing upon login

Tags: php, vue.js

so i have a login form where in iwant to show a error message if the account is not exsisting or the inputed account is incorrect. but the error message using snackbar is not showing.
here is my code for vue js.

```
const Login = Vue.component('login-view', {
    data () {
        return {
            validate: {
                login: false,
                forgot: false
            },
            loading: {
                login: false
            },
            form: {
                email: null,
                password: null
            },
            showPassword: false
        }
    },
    computed: {
        passField () {
          var type = null
          if (this.showPassword) {
            type = 'text'
          } else {
            type = 'password'
          }
          return type
        }
    },
    methods: {
      signIn () {
        if (this.$refs.login.validate()) {
          this.loading.login = true
          axios.post('./sql/login.php', this.form)
          .then((res) => {
            const data = res.data
            console.log(data)
            if(data) {
              sessionStorage.setItem('uid', data.uid)
              sessionStorage.setItem('displayName', data.displayName)
              sessionStorage.setItem('email', data.email)
              sessionStorage.setItem('type', data.type)
              if (data.type === 'customer') { router.push('/'); location.reload() }
              else if (data.type === 'seller') { router.push('/seller') }
            }
            this.loading.login = false
           })/* Catching the error and displaying it in the console. */
           .catch((error) => { console.log(error); this.$emit('snackbar', "incorrect"); this.loading.login = false })
        }
      }
    },
```

here is my code for php

```
<?php
    require_once("connection.php");
    // Used to recognize JSON data posted by Axios.js
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
    //Check if the account exists
    $sql = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
    $sql->execute(array($data['email']));
    $count = $sql->rowCount();
    // If account exists, its data will be fetched.
    if($count === 1) {
        $info = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $verified = password_verify($data['password'], $info->password);
        // Checks if password entered matches the hashed password in account's data.
        if ($verified) {
            // Encodes initial account information as a JSON and sends it back.
            $accountData = new \stdClass();
            $accountData->uid = $info->uid;
            $accountData->displayName = $info->fname . ' ' . $info->lname;
            $accountData->email = $info->email;
            $accountData->type = $info->type;
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            /* Encoding the account data as a JSON and sending it back to the client. */
            die(json_encode($accountData));
        } else {
            console_log(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 2000)));
            $error = 'Wrong email or password.  Please try again.';
            header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server');
            header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        /* Sending a JSON object back to the client. */
        
            die(json_encode(array('message' => 'ERROR', 'code' => 2000)));
        }
        die();
    } 
    else {
        $error = 'Account does not exists under this email.  Please try again.';
    }
    die();
    function console_log($output, $with_script_tags = true) {
        $js_code = 'console.log(' . json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_TAG) . 
        ');';
        if ($with_script_tags) {
                $js_code = '<script>' . $js_code . '</script>';
        }
        echo $js_code;
}
?>
```

here is the link to the website that i built. https://www.tailorshopthesis.online/tailorshop%20twofish/shop/#/sign-in
i hope some of you guys will help me. thanks

Comment: Do you have an event listener in your parent component which listens for the `snackbar` event which is emitted by your `login-view` component?

Comment: idont have an event listener for that.

Comment: Then who will show the snackbar with the error message?